# MySQL: MAX() of entire column *help*

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm having a little difficulty as I am an SQL newbie...

The question I am trying to answer is as follows:

Analyze active vs. discontinued products.  Show number of products, average standard price, low standard price and high standard price for each group.

Though, when I run my code the max/min/avg is just taken from each specific row and NOT the entire column like I need it to...

Here is my query so far:

```
select productId, prodName, stdUnitPrice, qtyPerUnit, discontinued, avg(stdUnitPrice), MAX(stdUnitPrice), min(stdUnitPrice)
from Product
group by discontinued, prodName, stdUnitPrice
```

I feel like there is an issue with what I'm grouping by... Any and all help would be great.

*Please keep answers SQL-noob friendly!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the number of products and not the actual products, remove those unneeded fields from the query/grouping.  That leaves with only grouping by the `discontinued` field.

```
select discontinued, avg(stdUnitPrice), MAX(stdUnitPrice), min(stdUnitPrice) 
from Product 
group by discontinued
```